# Close button in CTabFolderRenderer in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have a requirement to have a close `Button`(Native) in `CTabFolder` for close action. To say precisely I need a native Button with text  "**close**".
I have a `CustomCTabFolderRenderer` with `drawClose` method being overidden. I did manage to draw an image, but client didn't like that. Rather than drawing any polygon or image using the `GC` is there any way to draw a native Button? I could have drawn a rectangle with some text, but I'm worried that it cant give a native look. I would be pretty much happy even if I can get a solution to draw a **Windows OS** button(I mean any implentation that works just on windows)

Comment: I don't understand, the `CTabFolder` natively supports a close button. Can you elaborate why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Baz My requirement is not about functionality, but the Look and Feel. The Close button, as you said, is not a native button, but a polygon drawn in **X** shape using the `GC`. I need a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=80554), there is currently no way to draw native OS resources yourself, i.e. SWT does not supply methods to do this.

Furthermore, you can't subclass `CTabFolder` without a great amount of voodoo power.

---

As a conclusion: There is no "easy" way to do this. **If** it is possible, it would require *a lot* of work.

Comment: Baz - I agree with you. Finally I resorted to use a image which resembles a Button. Btw, I did't subclass `CTabFolder` but had to subclass `CTabFolderRenderer` for my requirement.