# Change look of close button of CTabFolder

Tags: java, swt

I would like to change tooltip for close button from "close" to "delete" and to replace an "x" with another image. I found the corresponding places in the code of SWT.

Class [CTabFolder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux/x86_64/3.6.0/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.java#3373):

```
String _getToolTip(int x, int y) {
    // ...
    if ((showClose || item.getShowClose()) && item.closeRect.contains(x, y)) {
        return SWT.getMessage("SWT_Close"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

Class [CTabFolderRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux/x86_64/3.7.0/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolderRenderer.java#CTabFolderRenderer.drawClose%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC%2Corg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle%2Cint%29):

```
void drawClose(GC gc, Rectangle closeRect, int closeImageState) {
    // ...
}
```

To my sorrow I noticed neither of both methods can be overridden. So is there really no chance to fulfill my requirement? And this although CTabFolderRenderer is even intended to be subclassed. User [Niranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781610/niranjan) asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658840/close-button-in-ctabfolderrenderer-in-swt) and he apparently managed to solve one of my problems. But how?

Comment: You could do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844119/how-to-add-close-button-with-swt-tabitem). In that case you'd have the icon on the left though.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new renderer to be used instead of `CTabFolderRenderer` by calling `CTabFolder.setRenderer`.

Your new renderer can extend `CTabFolderRenderer` but as you can't override `drawClose` you would have to override `draw` and duplicate a lot of code.

Eclipse itself uses a tab renderer `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering` to change some of the drawing (but not the close button).

So this is a lot more work that it might have been with a better base render class.